# Eloquent detach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()
```

It comes from the PollRepository :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Ici on doit supprimer le sondage d'identifiant $id
    // Il faut nettoyer les tables "polls", "answers" et "poll_user" (pour cette dernière pensez à la méthode "detach" qui simplifie la syntaxe)
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);
    $poll->answers()->detach();
    $poll->users()->detach();
    $poll->delete();
}
```

It is necessary to clean the tables "polls", "answers" and "poll_user" (for this last one think about the method "detach" which simplifies the syntax).

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61bQ3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `detach()` is available only for many-to-many relationships, you would need to change the way you are deleting relationships.

From your relationships diagram, it seems the relationship between `Poll` and `Answer` is not a many-to-many which makes total sense. However, `Poll` and `User` have a many-to-many relationship.

So the following should work:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $poll = Poll::findOrFail($id);

    $poll->answers()->delete();
    $poll->users()->detach();

    $poll->delete();
}
```

**Or:** this is a good case to use [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events). You could add the `deleting()` event to your `App\Poll` model.

```
class Poll extends Model
{
    // 
    //

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($poll) { 
            $poll->answers()->delete();
            $poll->users()->detach();
        });
    }
}
```

... and then every time you delete a Poll, you'd just need to do the following.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Poll::findOrFail($id)->delete();
}
```

The relationships will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `findOrFail()` method returns Eloquent collection, but not Eloquent model. Use `firstOrFail()` instead to get Eloquent model Poll. That way you'll be able to use detach() method.